# Django - How to get admin url from model instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to send an email to a user when a new model instance is saved and I want the email to include a link to the admin page for that model instance. Is there a way to get the correct URL? I figure Django must have that information stored somewhere.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This [Django snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1916/) should do:

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):

    def get_admin_url(self):
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.__class__)
        return reverse("admin:%s_%s_change" % (content_type.app_label, content_type.model), args=(self.id,))
```

The `self` refers to the parent model class, i.e. `self.id` refers to the object's instance `id`. You can also set it as a [`property`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) on the model by sticking the `@property` decorator  on top of the method signature.

**EDIT:** The answer by Chris Pratt [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10420949/1211429) saves a DB query over the `ContentType` table. My answer still "works", and is less dependent on the Django model `instance._meta` internals. FYI.

Comment: These answers don't seem to be working.  I just get back "/admin/tracker/order/2/".  How do I get the hostname?

Comment: @Greg Of course, `get_admin_url()` above gets you the part that goes after the hostname. Use the Django [sites](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/) framework to appropriately get the hostname of the current site. Then prefix it to the result of `get_admin_url()`.

Comment: Works fine in 1.8, too

Answer (score 68):

Not trying to rip off @JosvicZammit, but using `ContentType` is the wrong approach here. It's just a wasted DB query. You can get the require info from the `_meta` attribute:

```
from django.urls import reverse

info = (model_instance._meta.app_label, model_instance._meta.model_name)
admin_url = reverse('admin:%s_%s_change' % info, args=(model_instance.pk,))
```

Answer (score 13):

This gives the same result as Josvic Zammit's snippet, but does not hit the database:

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):

    def get_admin_url(self):
        return reverse("admin:%s_%s_change" % (self._meta.app_label, self._meta.model_name), args=(self.id,))
```

Comment: change attr `module_name` by `model_name` (`module_name` is undefined)

Comment: Django 1.8 renamed the 'module_name' attribute to 'model_name' in a Model's meta object. 
Code snippet updated ... thank you !

Comment: What if I have several AdminSite instances? How to get current one instead of `admin:`?

Comment: @EugZol, I would assign a name to each admin, then use it in reverse(). For example, in urlspatterns:  path('admin_ex/', admin_ex.urls, name="admin_ex"); then reverse('admin_ex:label_model_action'). Never had the need to use this in practice, however.

Comment: @MarioOrlandi Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Just use this one liner that is also python 3 ready:

```
from django.urls import reverse

reverse('admin:{0}_{1}_change'.format(self._meta.app_label, self._meta.model_name), args=(self.pk,))
```

More on this in the django admin site doc, [reversing admin urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls).

Comment: Should be `self._meta.model_name` rather than `self._meta.module_name`.

Comment: Thanks @nedned, fixing

Comment: Just because it’s possible:
`reverse('admin:{m.app_label}_{m.model_name}_change'.format(m=self._meta), args=[self.pk])`

Answer (score 5):

So, combining the answers by Chris, Josvic and Josh, here's a copy-paste method you can add into your model (tested on Django 1.8.3).

```
def get_admin_url(self):
    """the url to the Django admin interface for the model instance"""
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    info = (self._meta.app_label, self._meta.model_name)
    return reverse('admin:%s_%s_change' % info, args=(self.pk,))
```