# Custom tag for get admin url for a model. "type object 'str' has no attribute '_meta'" error

Tags: python, django, django-contenttypes

I'm trying to use this [snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1916/) for my custom templatetag and receive `AttributeError at /edit/:
type object 'str' has no attribute '_meta'`

customtag.py:

```
from django import template
from django.core import urlresolvers
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models
register = template.Library()

def get_admin_url(obj):
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj.__class__)
    return urlresolvers.reverse("admin:%s_%s_change" %    (content_type.app_label, content_type.model), args=(obj.id,))
    register.simple_tag(get_admin_url)
```

edit.html:

```
{% load customtag %}
  <p>You can also edit user data in <a href="{% get_admin_url obj %}">admin panel</a></p>
```

custom tag is where it should be(app/templatetags/customtag.py), app with it is in INSTALLED_APPS, Django==1.7
 I need contenttypes here since I want refer to any model. What I miss?I've looked through other similar solutions(e.g [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10420333/5287469) )but still can not solve the problem. How to prompt it to work? Any help would appreciated.

Full traceback is [here](https://gist.github.com/avkpol/09591841ba470ddd9a9bdab037984f95)

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing here. Why are you accepting `self` in a function that is not part of a class? And what is `object` in this context?

Comment: Thanks, of course you are right, in example it was inside Model class, I corrected but still `'str' has no attribute '_meta'`...

Comment: Can you please post the full traceback? And also show where `object` is coming from in the template and what it contains.

Comment: Please see traceback

Comment: I don't understand why you won't say what `object` is here. That is clearly the source of the problem.

Comment: Seems I really did not pass `object` from view context to html template..If you meant it.

Comment: Yes, I did it! I've passed `object` as `context['obj'] = obj` via  `get_context_data` method of `class `FormView` in my class based view and all start working.Thank you very much for valuable guidance! Arrange please your advice as answer for me to rate.